# TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()?

Tags: python

```
# Logistic Regression

# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Loan.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 16: 17 ].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 20].values


# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = 1)
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

When i write code i get error at the end like object of type 'int' has no len()?

Comment: Could you give the full traceback? I'd guess that `categorical_features = 1` is the cause, but it's hard to tell without a [mcve]. Looking at [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) that argument should be *"“all” or array of indices or mask"*, so why you're passing `1` is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It was fixed after a correction was made:

```
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1]*)
```

I think it's because python wants us to specify which column, explaining the need for "[]".